# How can we Generate a Definitive List of all Excel Connections

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tying to find a definitive list of all Excel tables, connection, connection strings, and anything else that Excel can connect to.  I know Excel can handle these kinds of connections.

```
QueryTables
ListObjects
Workbook Connections
```

Also, connections can consist of these types.

```
xlConnectionTypeODBC
xlConnectionTypeOLEDB
```

Is there any other way for Excel to import data or export data? Basically, I want to create an inventory of all connections (metadata) for a bunch of Excel Workbooks using VBA. I have some VBA that seems to be working, but I don't know if I'm capturing every possible type of connection.

Comment: [Broader list of connection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconnectiontype). The [`WorkbookConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection) docs may be helpful.

Comment: Wow! That's quite a list. I need to dig into this tomorrow. Thanks for sharing this information!!